# How To Exclude Specific Exception From @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, transactions, rollback

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public void abc()
{
 try{
  //some Code
  }
  catch(DataIntegrityViolationException ex)
  {
   //some Code
  }
}
```

in above code , How can i exclude DataIntegrityViolationException from rollbacking this transaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `noRollbackFor` attribute. Example:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
```

By default `@Transactional` works only for `RuntimeException`s and `Error`s, but not on checked exceptions.

So if you **really** want to rollback a transaction for every exception except the `DataIntegrityViolationException` you should specify `rollbackFor` attribute as well:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class, noRollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
```

Comment: So will it RollbackFor Any Throwable Expect DataIntegrityViolationException? 

or i have to code like :


`@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor= Throwable.class ,noRollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)`